# Round to nearest 2 decimal

Tags: javascript, math

```
var ts = (100-st).tofixed(2);
```

Shouldn't this give me the result of `100-st` to the nearest 2nd decimal place?

Edit: It always returns the value of 100.

Comment: Please add a programming language tag...

Comment: Timrau has provided the correct answer. And to confirm, the solution was tested with different browsers and conditions. If there is still a problem then it must be with some other piece of code that was not included in the question.

Answer (score 4):

It should be

```
var ts = (100-st).toFixed(2)
```

Note that the function names are case *sensitive*.

Comment: ts and st are two different variables. I want my end result (TS) be the result of subracting the value of (ST) from a total possible of 100 points.

Comment: @NathanGraff My typo.

Comment: I corrected my issue, and still returns 100. I've checked the field calculation order, and everything checks out but still nothing.

Comment: @NathanGraff Show more code. How did you get `st`?

Comment: Simple field notation of Totals*4.16.
Totals is just the sum of a number of boxes.

Comment: @NathanGraff Use `console.log()` to print `st` before evaluating `ts`. Make sure `st` is non-0.